# Simplest possible implementation of critical section?

Tags: c++, critical-section

In one of my C++ methods I have to do this in such a way that only one thread access this piece of code at a given time.

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    //critical section starts
    someValue++;
    someVariable = someValue
    //critical section ends
}
```

Can anyone guide me what would be the most simplest and preferably smallest(code wise) possible way to achieve this? I don't want to use `Boost Library` and I don't want to make a mess in my code just to achieve this. I am looking for a standard C++ solution not something that only works in Windows.

Comment: Won't this - by nature of being about threads - be platform specific? I don't think c++ knows about threads yet.

Comment: You absolutely *must* have platform support for concurrent programming. Standard C++98/03 *does not have it*. One answer would be `pthreads`. Or use C++0x, which does have it and you can use `<mutex>`.

Comment: I am writing a code that it supposed to be run under multiple platforms :(

Comment: Kerrek: Don't forget `boost`!

Comment: @rubenvb _I don't want to use Boost Library..._

Comment: You can use spinlocks, however they will be more complex, more buggy and a lot less performant than a proper solution with mutexes.

Comment: @Haris one way you could go is to write a class with the proper `#ifdef`s that will expose the same interface but work correctly/differently internally on different platforms. I did this with a simple threading library and it works acceptably (for me at least).

Comment: And BTW the mutex from boost::threads is pretty much exactly what made it into the C++0x standard. I highly recommend giving that a try if you can't go to C++0x.

Comment: I feel the urge to downvote for wanting to write a portable code and at the same time excluding boost as an option, although boost actually has a portable implementation of the following standard library threads.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie Not a bad idea, could be the last option :)

Comment: I don't have much experience in C++, through the comments it seems it is not a simple thing as I was expecting. I guess I would have to go for boost anyways. The reason was dependency on some lib which I wanted to avoid

Comment: You already have a dependency on some platform agnostic thread library right (that's why you want a mutex)? Use that library's mutex, you already have the dependency.

Comment: you'll have to do some #defines. Use pthread mutex on posix systems and enter/leave critical section on windows.  Theres no c++ define to do it. Or maybe there is in the new cxx standard (but I guess you're using visual studio so that's out of the question).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Boost... You might be interested in [Dekker's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm), [Peterson's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm) and [Lamport's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm) algorithms. But I am not pretty sure that their practical implementation will work fine.